# Wordpress : Get Page_id when permalink set to Post name

Tags: wordpress

i want the page_id of current page in wordpress if the permalink set to post name. i have used `get_query_var('page_id')`, but it is not working .What is the solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $page = get_query_var( 'page_id', 1 );
```